# Testing with unirest- java

Tags: java, unirest

Currently, I'm working in unirest java. This is a sample Url. Here parameters s is device secret and  m is mac address and d is device id http://baseUrl.com?s=235&m=12:25:14:25&d=25

> Now i want to automate different test cases like :   null mac, null
>   device id, null device secret  different type of device id.. like all
>   characters., all numbesrs, mix of character n numbers special
>   character set etc

Here is my code :

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;

/**
 * Created by naveen on 12/12/16.
 */
public class uniresttest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        final HttpResponse<String> response= Unirest.get("http://baseUrl.com?s=235&m=12:25:14:25&d=25").asString();
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

> > **1) Success Scenario:-**
> >
> > Input : http://baseUrl/device?s=b30b33&m=d3r34ret34t5r&d=8
>
> **Output Json :**
>
> {"level":"info","msg":"REG_DEV_01","meta":[]}

**2) Scenario :-**
REG_DEV_PRMS_1_00   ---error    ----Mandatory params are missing - Device Secret    ----Any of the Params are missing

**3) Scenario :-**
REG_DEV_PRMS_2_00   ----error   ----Mandatory params are missing - Mac Address  ------Any of the Params are missing

**4) Scenario :-**
REG_DEV_PRMS_3_00   ----error   ----Mandatory params are missing - Device Id    -----Any of the Params are missing

**5) Scenario :-**
REG_DEV_EXISTS_00   ----error   ----Device with same mac address already exists ----Already existing registered device

**6) Sceanrio :-**
REG_DEV_1_00    ---error    ----Device secret does not mactches for the supplied device id  ----same

**7) Sceanrio**
REG_DEV_01  info    ----Device Registered Successfully  -----same

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130495/discussion-on-question-by-xtremetester-testing-with-unirest-java).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample JUnit tests using Unirest for scenarios 1, 2, 3 and 4.

You can write tests similarly for scenarios 5, 6 and 7.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

//http://localhost:8080?s=235&m=12:25:14:25&d=25

public class RestTestUsingUniRest {

    @Test
    public void checkTheSuccessScenario() throws UnirestException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080/device?s=30&m=12:12:25&d=8")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .asJson();

        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(jsonResponse);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("info", jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().get("level"));
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("REG_DEV_01", jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().get("msg"));
    }

    @Test
    public void deviceSecretIsMissing() throws UnirestException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080?m=12:25:14:25&d=25")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .asJson();

        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(jsonResponse);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("REG_DEV_PRMS_1_00", jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().get("msg"));
    }


    @Test
    public void macAddressIsMissing() throws UnirestException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080/device?s=30&d=8")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .asJson();

        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(jsonResponse);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("REG_DEV_PRMS_2_00", jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().get("msg"));
    }

    @Test
    public void deviceIdIsMissing() throws UnirestException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080?m=12:25:14:25")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .asJson();

        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(jsonResponse);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("REG_DEV_PRMS_3_00", jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().get("msg"));
    }


}
```

Hope you already have this JAR. If not, you can get the Unirest Java JAR from Maven using the below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: These tests fail if you don't have a local server set up to listen at 8080 that returns the appropriate results.